# C: using function to get input in different format

Tags: c

I am an extreme newbie in C, I wrote following code:

```c
# include <stdio.h>

static char * getInfo(char info[15]){
    static char res[15];
    printf("Please enter your %s:\n", info);
    scanf("%s", res);
    return res;
}

static int getNum(char info[15]){
    static int res;
    printf("Please enter your %s:\n", info);
    scanf("%d", &res);
    return res;
}

int main(){
    static char * name;
    static char * title;
    name = getInfo("name");
    title = getInfo("title");
    
    int age;
    age = getNum("age");
    
    printf("Welcome %s %s age %d\n", name, title, age);
    return 0;
}

/*
Please enter your name:
Ben
Please enter your title:
Hansan
Please enter your age:
32
Welcome Hansan Hansan age 32
Program ended with exit code: 0
*/
```

I am trying to get input of string and integer format using functions.

I don't understand why `Hansan` is duplicated, I will be so glad if someone offers some suggestions.

Comment: It seems like you've just discovered the `static` keyword and are using it for everything.  The issue of course is that `getInfo` has a single static array, and it always returns a pointer to that array.  That pointer never changes, because that's how static storage duration works.  If you want to store the results from multiple calls to that function, you'll need to _copy_ the string, not just store the pointer.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", res);` 1) there are LOTS of ways the user can cause this statement to fail.  The easiest would be to input more than 14 characters.  Suggest: `if( scanf("%14s", res) != 1 ) { //handle error }`  Note the MAX CHARACTERS modifier `14` which is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input.  Note the returned value MUST be 1 (number of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers).   Similar returned value checking needed for `scanf("%d", &res);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using `static` variable
to store the input, static variable always holds the latest data stored in it.

```
static char * getInfo(char info[15]){
    static char res[15];
    printf("Please enter your %s:\n", info);
    scanf("%s", res);
    return res;
}
```

change it to

```
char * getInfo(char info[15]){
    char *res = malloc(15);
    printf("Please enter your %s:\n", info);
    scanf("%s", res);
    return res;
}
```

and `free` the memory once done processing in main.

```
  int main(){
    char * name;
    char * title;
    name = getInfo("name");
    title = getInfo("title");
    
    int age;
    age = getNum("age");
    
    printf("Welcome %s %s age %d\n", name, title, age);

    free(name);
    free(title);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did not call `free` in all my previous code!!! will they still exist?

Comment: @duck You can't `free` static variable, in latest code we have added `free` because I'm allocating the memory runtime using `malloc`.

Comment: Do I need to use `free` if I define a `const char` method?